# jFreeChart: Is this kind of chart possible?

Tags: jfreechart

Is this kind of XY Chart with deviation possible to create in jFreeChart?
Thanks!
[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1144075/chart.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1144075/chart.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes - have a look at the DeviationRendererDemo2.java from the JFreeChartDemo collection

Comment: got everything except for the litle square markers on the lines. how can I achieve that?